# Confused with Apple Map Vs Google Map

Tags: ios, mkmapview

This might be a very stupid question for some people but I want to be make sure about this. 
In iOS6 Apple has updated its Map application and added his own map. Now if I develop any native application and include map(MKMapView) into this so are their any changes which I should be aware of them?

Previously, I was using Google web service to fetch the latitude and longitude between two locations and draw direction. Does Apple provide its own web services for the same?

Comment: Unless a method has been deprecated it should still work. Does it matter where the data comes from?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Early users of Apple's maps seemed to feel that it does matter where the data comes from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> are their any changes which I should be aware of them?

MKMapView will still work fine, but the map it displays will look a little different. Also, if  you limit your app to iOS versions that use only Apple's maps, you might not be subject to Google's terms and conditions. *Read your agreements.*

> Does Apple provide its own web services for the same?

There's [`CLGeocoder`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html). It's a class, not a web service, but that just makes it easier to use.

Answer (score 2):

Using MKMapView framework didn't change just because the images are different. It should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Google's Terms Of Service say that you can't show their data on someone else's maps. So if your app is still getting data from a Google webservice you'll need to use the Google Map SDK that they have put out, not the usual MKMapView on iOS 6+.
If you are only using Google's webservice to turn a human readable address into lat/long then you can do that using CLGeocoder as Caleb suggested, but Google offer other services too.